# How to overwrite strings within an if-loop in Swift

Tags: string, swift, if-statement

I have a few variables that I create within code for a view controller (basically, I'm just checking the values of segmented controls), but when I try to write into the string within the loops (shown below), nothing is written, and all strings remain "nil."

```
var textTypeVideo:String?
var textMultipleAgents:String?
var textAdditionalRooms:String?
var textMultipleVideos:String?
var textTurnaround:String?
```

Here are the functions that check to see where the segmented controls are:

```
@IBAction func typeOfVideoAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if typeOfVideoControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        textTypeVideo = "Standard Home Video"
    } else {
        textTypeVideo = "Standard CV Video"
    }
}

@IBAction func mulitpleAgentScenesAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if multipleAgentScenesControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        textMultipleAgents = "Multiple Agent Scenes Desired"
    } else {
        textMultipleAgents = "No Multiple Agent Scenes"
    }
}

@IBAction func additionalRoomsAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if additionalRoomsFeaturesControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        textAdditionalRooms = "Additional Rooms & Features Desired"
    } else {
        textAdditionalRooms = "No Additional Rooms & Features"
    }
}

@IBAction func multipleVideosAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if multipleVideoCopiesControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        textMultipleVideos = "Second Video Copy Requested"
    } else {
        textMultipleVideos = "No Second Video Copy"
    }
}

@IBAction func turnaroundAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if turnaroundControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        textTurnaround = "No Quick Turnaround"
    } else if turnaroundControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        textTurnaround = "24 Hour Turnaround Desired"
    } else if turnaroundControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        textTurnaround = "2 Business Day Turnaround Desired"
    } else if turnaroundControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
        textTurnaround = "3 Business Day Turnaround Desired"
    } else {
        textTurnaround = "5 Business Day Turnaround Desired"
    }
}
```

Finally, this is what I want to fill in and print in an email:

```
   let messageBody = "\(textTypeVideo) and \(textMultipleAgents) and \(textAdditionalRooms) and \(textMultipleVideos) and \(textTurnaround)"
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I just can't seem to fill in the top variables with what they're supposed to be, based on the segmented controls! Thanks.

Comment: Do above functions run? You put the breakpoint in these functions and see if it breaks.

Comment: Where are you checking their value and they are nil? As far as what I can see above that looks fine, except since the top variables are Optionals (String?), when you print out the messageBody, each variable may print out as "Optional( string ), but this still wouldn't make it be nil.

Comment: Everything runs well -- I just have them in a composed email and "nil and nil and..." comes up for the subject.

Comment: Did you put `print` statements to test and see whether or not all the IBActions are being called? Maybe beneath the if/else clauses you could put `print(variableName)` and see if it even executes.

Comment: if the above methods are not helping, then the only thing I can think of adding that may help is are you creating multiple instances of the view controller or view, or is there something that may be wiping out the text before the messageBody is created

Comment: I'll give the "print" a try!

Comment: I tried print and it worked -- it printed Optional("correct text")

Comment: Can you just verify the flow of functions , may be the mail composer is set first and then the individual functions are called, or if you could post the entire code , that would be helpful

Comment: I figured it out actually by changing the sender: AnyObject? to UISegmented Control and it worked... No idea really why it worked, but it worked! It could be just a small issue with the sender within the functions.